# return array of json in swift

Tags: ios, swift

i have elementary problem in swift, 
 this is my json :

```
{
1: 2,
2: 27,
3: 43,
4: 0,
5: 0,
6: 0,
7: 24,
8: 22,
9: 11,
10: 0,
11: 0,
12: 0,
13: 7,
14: 0,
15: 0,
16: 0,
17: 0,
18: 0,
19: 0,
20: 0,
}
```

i want set this value in my array by below code but it not work:

```
 let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                guard let jsonval = jsonData as? [String:AnyObject] else { return }

                var num = [Int]()

                for i in 1 ..< 20 {

                    num[i] = jsonval[i] as! Int

                }
```

what is solution???
thanks

Comment: This is not valid JSON. In JSON, dictionaries have STRINGS as keys, not integers.

Comment: how can i print them????

Comment: Other than the clear problems already stated with your code, you should never just say "but it not work" (which is gramatically wrong as well), but you should always explain the specific issue you have and include any errors that you get in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the Json to this format:

```
{"1":2,"2":27,...}
```

Change the loop to:

```
    for i in 1 ... 20 {
        if let value = jsonval["\(i)"] as? Int {
            num.append(value)
            print(value)
        }
    }
```

Then you will have the array with elements from Json, and print them by the way.